# Changing the MySQL query delimiter through the C API

Tags: c, mysql

How can I change the MySQL query delimiter using the C API? I tried sending `DELIMITER |` as a query, complained about `..the right syntax to use near 'delimiter' at line 1`..

Tried `DELIMITER |;` too, no luck. Tried `DELIMITER |; SELECT 1|`, no luck. :(

The reason I ask is that I need to create a trigger through the C API such as the following:

```
create trigger increase_count after insert on torrent_clients for each row
begin
   IF NEW.BytesLeft = 0 THEN
      UPDATE torrents SET Seeders = Seeders + 1 WHERE torrents.InfoHash = NEW.InfoHash;
   ELSE
      UPDATE torrents SET Leechers = Leechers + 1 WHERE torrents.InfoHash = NEW.InfoHash;
   END IF;
end|
```

but I don't think there is a way to do it without changing the delimiter, is there?

Thanks!

---

EDIT: Note that I do need to explicitly write the delimiter at the end, as I'm running multiple queries with only one API call (I have multi statements on)

---

EDIT2: the mysqlclient that uses the C api does this so there must be a way..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the delimiter is only needed when using the `mysql` client program (because it is *`mysql`* that interpretes the semicolon as statement delimiter). [You don't need to change the delimiter when using the C API](https://books.google.de/books?id=s_87mv-Eo4AC&lpg=PA567&hl=de&pg=PA535):

> Normally, you can execute only a single SQL command with [`mysql_query()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-query.html). A semicolon can appear in such a command only when it is syntactically allowed, and that is normally not the case! In particular, SQL does not allow for a command to end in a semicolon. (The C API will raise an error if you attempt to do so.)
>
> The commands `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE TRIGGER`, and the like are exceptions when they define a stored procedure or trigger: In such commands the semicolon serves as a separator between the SQL instructions that are part of the stored procedure or trigger. Such commands can be executed without problem.

P.S. You probably should set [multi statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html) off again.

Comment: This is an old post but thanks for your answer . Could you please explain why to turn off `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`  in order to ensure compound statements like `CREATE PROCEDURE` work well without error in C API like  `mysql_real_query()` ? and where can I find further detail about this ? (have been reading mysql documentation but I'm still struggling to understand , thanks)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multiple commands using mysql_query. You will have to set some parameters though while establishing the connection.
e.g., 
unsigned long opt_flags = CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS  | CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS |                            CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS ;

if (0 == mysql_real_connect(mConn,mHostName,mUserName,mUserPass,mDbName,mPort,0,opt_flags))
...

/* execute multiple statements */
status = mysql_query(mysql,
                     "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;\
                      CREATE TABLE test_table(id INT);\
                      INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(10);\
                      UPDATE test_table SET id=20 WHERE id=10;\
                      SELECT * FROM test_table;\
                      DROP TABLE test_table");

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

```
DELIMITER //
```

Without a ";" at the end? It might be not possible to change the delimiter within a query that has multiple queries in it.