# Change MySQL ending statement

Tags: mysql

This question I am asking by proxy (it is for someone else).

He is making a program and have the following problem: He need to input unescaped ";" into a query, he heard that he could ask MySQL to terminate with something else than ";"

So, in pseudocode it would be:

Change_Statement_Ending(;;);
SELECT * FROM * WHERE;; //suppose that this was a input query, it is years that I don't use SQL I don't remember...
Change_Statement_Ending(;);;

The problem is that he cannot remember the correct syntax for the line that I wrote as "Change_Statement_Ending(ending)"

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109366/changing-the-mysql-query-delimiter-through-the-c-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DELIMITER` . E.g to change the delimiter to `//` instead of the default `;` , issue `DELIMITER  //`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a little time back, but someone told me that it's a not very good. I then found that I had a bad query written there and did rewrite it. So maybe you should first look at the query?

I will check for my solution and edit with answer.

I had this query: http://pastebin.com/LZkFF6wR
And because of that `&amp;` inside of it it wouldn't run unless delimiter was changed.
So, I then used `htmlspecialchars()` - [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) - for my query (since it was PHP generated, don't know about yours) and it fixed the issue.